# Create extension method in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Normally When I create a custom class I can create a function that uses that class as a parameter for example:

```
class Sphere{
    double calculateRadius() {return 40.0;}
}
```

So I can then call Sphere.calculateRadius().

But with pre-existing classes like for example the String one, this can't be done. For Example. I've tried doing something like:

```
String.createFrom(String s){return "new";}
```

but it doesn't work (Android Studio doesn't even make me compile.).

Is this possible, and if it is, how could I do it in Dart? And If I created it, how would I access the object I called the method from? (the String in the example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now January 2020, Dart 2.7 officially introduced extension methods.
To extend a class, this can be done:

```
extension NewExtension on double {
  int get myMethod {
    return (1/this*10).toInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean extension methods. That's not yet supported but the Dart team made attempts already to design such a feature and the chances are good it will be added to the language

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/41

Comment: That's what I meant! there was no way I could figure it out by myself thank you! I'm going to edit the question!

Answer (score 2):

Use  **Extension method**

**Use the following syntax to create an extension:**

```
extension <extension name> on <type> {
  (<member definition>)*
}
```

**Example :**

```
extension MyString on String {
  String addHello() {
    return 'Hello : $this';
  }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
 void main() {
      var name = 'Kab';
      var nameWithHello = name.addHello();
      print(nameWithHello);
    }
```

**Output :**  `Hello : Kab`

Your can learn more here : [Dart Extension In Flutter](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

Comment: Yes, I can see that the question is old when it was not supported but now it is supporting it. and you explained it very well.